# Wireles adapter not working after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04

My Lenovo thinkpad E490 stopped having wireless connectivity after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. 
With my little knowledge of Ubuntu i started researching and i think i know my wireless adapter can be described as RTL8822BE.

I started trying `ls sudo lshw -class network` and the wirless adapter was present but not working.

After going to the repo https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new and following the instructions the adappter even dissapeared from that list.

The output of `lspci -nn` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller [8086:3e34] (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [8086:3ea0] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller [8086:9df9] (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller [8086:9ded] (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM [8086:9def] (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9de0] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9db8] (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:9db0] (rev f0)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9db2] (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 [8086:9db4] (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d84] (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9dc8] (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9da3] (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller [8086:9da4] (rev 30)
02:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8621] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
07:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba Corporation BG3 NVMe SSD Controller [1179:0113] (rev 01)
```

Ad you can see: `Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]`. I wander if that is related.

I would like to know if there is any chance to fix this before deciding to format my system and install 19.10 again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a driver for the wireless adapter. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS.